# Convert Coordinate Notation with specified number of decimals

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcgis-pro, convert

I have two columns with decimal degrees: POINT_X POINT_Y.

I then use the tool Convert Coordinate Notation to convert from DD to DDM. But I get too many decimals, see picture.
In the "Format Location Units" I have specified 3 decimals.

Is it possible to use this tool, and get 3 decimals in the output?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The Location Unit Format dialog you show in your question affects the display of coordinates in the status bar. The tool *Convert Coordinate Notation* has no parameter or environment setting that influences the number of decimal places in its output. Finally the output of the tool is a *text* field because the values it creates, as shown in your screen shot, contain spaces and letters.

So a simple calculate script manipulating the text could be used to truncate the coordinates as shown below:

[image: Calculate field tool]

Code block is:

```py
def truncate(dms):
    aL = dms.split(" ")
    lat = aL[1]
    lon = aL[3]
    # find decimal point
    lat_dp_idx =lat.find(".")
    lon_dp_idx =lon.find(".")
    
    # Truncate to 3 dp
    new_lat = lat[:lat_dp_idx+4]
    new_lon = lon[:lon_dp_idx+4]
    
    # rebuild DMS
    new = aL[0] + " " + new_lat + lat[-1] + " " + aL[2] + " " + new_lon + lon[-1]
    return new
```

Comment: This is great! The only drawback is that the function doesnt round the values: 62 50.32799993N will be 62 50.327N, but should round to  62 50.328N

Is that possible to include?

Comment: You could include a python round() function into this code if you want rounding, I leave that for to you to discover.